# knit multiple styles to a single pdf

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, r-markdown

I am currently putting together my dissertation with the help of rMarkdown but am running into a roadblock. Because each study (chapter) in the document must be in the format of the submitted journal, I have created each document as separate .Rmd files. When using an index.Rmd file to knit each chapter together into a single document, I lose the individual styling. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Could you knit and merge the individual files instead of merge and knit?

Comment: I was considering that as an option, however, I need references from each chapter to form a single bibliography at the end of the document. To my knowledge, knitting separately does not allow this.